# How to add Windows to grub?

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, grub, efi

The following is the list that I got when I executed the command `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 120.0 Gb, 120034123776 bytes
Id disk: 0x975e4baf

/dev/sdc1   *        2048      206847      102400   17  Скрытый HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdc2          206848   234437133   117115143    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

On this disk windows is located, I'm trying to write in GRUB file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

```
menuentry "Win7" {
     set root='(hd2,0)'
     chainloader +1
}

menuentry "Win71" {
     set root='(hd2,1)'
     chainloader +1
}
```

And update GRUB config `sudo update-grub`. In boot loader I see new items, but when I click It I see error:

```
invalid efi file path
```

Or

```
disk not found
```

I tried different combinations of `(hd2,0)` starting from `hd1,0` to `hd3,2` nothing works, what can I else do? Windows 7 has XP loader, that was installed after crash. When I load computer from windows disk it's loading correctly.

```
$ lsblk
NAME                       MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                          8:0    0  55,9G  0 disk 
├─sda1                       8:1    0   487M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                       8:2    0   244M  0 part /boot
└─sda3                       8:3    0  55,2G  0 part 
  ├─mint--vg-root (dm-0)   252:0    0  47,2G  0 lvm  /
  └─mint--vg-swap_1 (dm-1) 252:1    0     8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                          8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1                       8:17   0 931,5G  0 part /media/alex/media
sdc                          8:32   0 111,8G  0 disk 
├─sdc1                       8:33   0   100M  0 part 
└─sdc2                       8:34   0 111,7G  0 part /media/alex/win7
sr0                         11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path has to look like this:

```
menuentry "Windows 7" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod chain
    set root='(hd0,gpt1)'
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

It's because you are running on an EFI system, you can't use BIOS setup to start grub.

Comment: Just tried, the boot menu refresh (flickering) when i click this item

Comment: Did you actually change it to fit your installation? seeing as you are using hd2, you might want to change that in the **set root** part, as well as selecting the correct **gpt** partion.

Comment: Just tried `hd2,gpt1` `hd2,gpt0` `hd2,gpt2` and hd1,gpt(02) nothing work, error - disk hd2,gpt1 not found. How to understand what numbers should i use?

Comment: If you boot into the linux partition, you should be able to use some of these: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-list-disk-partitions-command/

To identify the drive you need to use. Also do you really have 3 harddrives and windows on the 3rd harddrive, cos that is what hd2 means?

Comment: Yes I do have 3 harddrives and sdc - it's third I think

Comment: I added some info to question

Comment: Oh yeah I also just noticed that it read sdc, sorry. Well did you by any chance do any changes in the EFI to install linux?
If not, did you at any point change the system from BIOS mode to EFI mode or the other way around?

Comment: It seems that hd2, gpt1 or hd2, gpt0 should work. :/
Did you also remember to add the **insmod** parts?
Also from that overview, it really looks like your windows might be running in BIOS mode, but I might be wrong. :s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23139/discussion-between-alex-and-kris).